# autossh configuration for accessing a system in private subnet

Tags: ssh-tunneling, autossh

Want to set up a proxy to access a system in a private subnet.

- We have a system A in our Office network.
- System B and System C are in cloud. System B has a public IP.
- Need to access System C in Cloud.

I am trying to use autossh to accomplish this. This is what i have done:

- Password less SSH access from System A to System B is setup.
- Passwordless SSH Access from System B to System C is setup.
- Running autossh as a systemd service on System B:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -4 -N sshuser@System A -g \
  -R 0.0.0.0:1234:System C:1234 \
  -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After this when i access System C:1234 i don't get the resource. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion: try to run just `ssh` on its own first. Once it does what you want, you can move on to `autossh`. If you've already done that and would like to have us take a look at the problem, please Include the (redacted if needed) output from the commands that do not work as expected.

Comment: Can you please help me with the command ? I am trying to setup a ssh reverse tunnel from System B (In my above example).

Comment: Search for `ssh jump host`. For example [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-ssh-to-proxy-through-a-linux-jump-host/) could help. If you run into problems, come back and please try to follow the advice on my previous comment, on how to report them.

Comment: Thank you. I was unable to connect via SSH as the port was already taken. Resolving that fixed the issue for me. :) Thanks again.